# #1111 - Invalid use of group function - MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Well, I am using the following query, however I am receiving the following error (#1111 - Invalid use of group function). Here's the query:

```
SELECT 
    a.`wo_number`,
    a.`crew_est`,
    a.`manhour_est`,
    b.`act_hours`,
    a.`status`,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN a.`status` = 'FINISH' THEN SUM(a.`status`)
        ELSE 0
    END) / SUM(a.`crew_est` * a.`manhour_est`) AS `total_percentage`
FROM
    `table_a` AS a
        LEFT JOIN
    `table_b` AS b ON a.`wo_number` = b.`wo_number`
WHERE
    a.`wo_number` = 'some_number'
GROUP BY a.`wo_number` , a.`sheet` , a.`serial`
```

If I remove the SUM() inside CASE WHEN THEN, then the query works. However, I do not get an accurate result for my need.

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need the nested sum of the `status` field? Also, why SUMming that text field `status`?

Answer (score 0):

You are nesting the SUM function, which isn't allowed.

You probably want this:

```
SELECT 
    a.`wo_number`,
    a.`crew_est`,
    a.`manhour_est`,
    b.`act_hours`,
    a.`status`,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN a.`status` = 'FINISH' THEN 1 -- or the column you want to aggregate
    END) / SUM(a.`crew_est` * a.`manhour_est`) AS `total_percentage`
FROM
    `table_a` AS a
        LEFT JOIN
    `table_b` AS b ON a.`wo_number` = b.`wo_number`
WHERE
    a.`wo_number` = 'some_number'
GROUP BY a.`wo_number` , a.`sheet` , a.`serial`
```

Also, shorthand for

```
SUM(CASE
        WHEN a.`status` = 'FINISH' THEN 1
    END)
```

is

```
SUM(a.`status` = 'FINISH')
```

Comment: I tried the query, it's working but the result doesn't fit my need. I try to convert excel formulas to mysql query. Here's the Excel formula: =SUMIF(E$3:E$19,"FINISH",D$3:D$19) / SUM(D$3:D$19) where E$3:E$19 = status, FINISH is the condition, and D$3:D$19 is (a.crew_est * a.manhour_est)

Comment: And what would that be? Why are you summing a text column "status"?